# Adding a middleware layer between GWT client and GWT servlet

Tags: java, servlets, gwt, rpc, middleware

Is that possible to add a layer in the middle of GWT client and GWT servlet where this layer will accept GWT client RPC request and do some processing and pass the request to GWT servlet, then GWT servlet responds back to this middle layer and the middle layer will pass it back to the client after processing.

**EDIT:** 
The layer is a total independent middleware which has nothing to do with GWT, it treats them as HTTP request and response. What it does is to log the request, perform authentication, filter the response payload, etc. It is a ready software(middleware).

To clarify, my question is **not** how to create this middle layer, but how could I possibly configure/program GWT client & Servlet in order to achieve this design.

Refer to image below for better understanding.

Any suggestion/idea is appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "some processing"?

Comment: Without a lot more detail, I'd say you're looking for a servlet Filter - it can look at the request, stop it from happening or allow it to continue, could even be made to read the incoming stream (after some effort), and gets a chance to do something before/after the servlet has done its work. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html

Comment: Added some info to clarify my question, thank you. Servlet filter is not what I'm looking for.